# Error: invalid parameter value on EmailMessage-Email Message Layout - Email-to-Case.layout

Tags: deployment, page-layout, emailmessage

I know that `Error: invalid parameter value` is a pretty common component failure, typically with profiles/permission sets - but this post is specifically related to new functionality in Summer '16, and there are no other questions here on SFSE about this failure on a page layout.

A deployment failed with this error:

```
1.  layouts/EmailMessage-Email Message Layout - Email-to-Case.layout -- Error: invalid parameter value
```

We have not modified the metadata for this file in any way. The layout in the target org was created automatically during an org upgrade (the change was authored by "Automated Process," evidenced below), as "Email Message" appears to be new functionality in Summer '16.

Has anyone else encountered this error, and if so, what was the resolution?

[image]

[image]

Here is the metadata for the layout in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Layout xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <layoutSections>
        <customLabel>false</customLabel>
        <detailHeading>true</detailHeading>
        <editHeading>true</editHeading>
        <label>Information</label>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>ParentId</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>MessageDate</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>CreatedById</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>Status</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>LastModifiedById</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <style>TwoColumnsTopToBottom</style>
    </layoutSections>
    <layoutSections>
        <customLabel>false</customLabel>
        <detailHeading>true</detailHeading>
        <editHeading>true</editHeading>
        <label>Address Information</label>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>FromAddress</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>FromName</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>ToAddress</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>CcAddress</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>BccAddress</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <style>OneColumn</style>
    </layoutSections>
    <layoutSections>
        <customLabel>false</customLabel>
        <detailHeading>true</detailHeading>
        <editHeading>true</editHeading>
        <label>Message Content</label>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>Subject</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>HtmlBody</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <behavior>Edit</behavior>
                <field>TextBody</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <style>OneColumn</style>
    </layoutSections>
    <layoutSections>
        <customLabel>false</customLabel>
        <detailHeading>false</detailHeading>
        <editHeading>false</editHeading>
        <layoutColumns/>
        <style>CustomLinks</style>
    </layoutSections>
    <relatedLists>
        <relatedList>RelatedAttachmentList</relatedList>
    </relatedLists>
    <relatedLists>
        <fields>CreatedDate</fields>
        <fields>StepStatus</fields>
        <fields>OriginalActor</fields>
        <fields>Actor</fields>
        <fields>Comments</fields>
        <relatedList>RelatedProcessHistoryList</relatedList>
    </relatedLists>
    <showEmailCheckbox>false</showEmailCheckbox>
    <showRunAssignmentRulesCheckbox>false</showRunAssignmentRulesCheckbox>
    <showSubmitAndAttachButton>false</showSubmitAndAttachButton>
</Layout>
```

Comment: I assume you are deploying with a package.xml at v37.0?

Comment: @cropredy that's a good idea! i checked, and it was 36.0, but it still threw the same error when I updated it to 37.0. thanks for the suggestion though! p.s. go blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out that this deployment error comes from including this related list metadata in the **layouts/EmailMessage-Email Message Layout.layout** file:

```
    <relatedLists>
        <fields>NAME</fields>
        <fields>TYPE</fields>
        <relatedList>RelatedEmailMessagePeopleList</relatedList>
    </relatedLists>
```

This comes from the "Sender and Recipients" related list on that layout. I'd recommend either removing that related list in the source org, adding it to the destination org, or filtering out that XML from the metadata you deploy.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Running a deploy from the same repository to a different target org did not generate the error; for now, I'm chalking this up as a platform quirk specific to the one org.

**EDIT:** We refreshed the org that was generating this issue, and the error disappeared; however, it eventually reappeared. Frustratingly, it reappeared seemingly out of nowhere - I made a commit to a different layout, then reverted that commit, ran a deployment, and the error reappeared.

Removing the `EmailMessage-Email Message Layout - Email-to-Case.layout` from our repository got rid of the error for now. I am not going to mark this as accepted, as I would still be interested to hear from anyone who could shed some light (even speculation) on this issue.